# Can someone explain to me what the correct way to pass the data is?

Tags: reactjs

Consider this scenario: there is only 1 screen in the app - `App.js`.

There are 5 components on that screen: `compA, compB, ...`

So there is only 1 api to get the all the data using for this app:

```
axios.get('database/getAll')
```

Let's say there are 100 objects returned from the api. Take not that I only want to pass only a subset of data to each component.

**Scenario 1**

I call the API in the screen `App.js`. Then I also pass all the data to every component. Meaning I pass all 100 object to each component, and filter the data in the component

**Scenario 2**

I call the API in `App.js`. I filter the data in the `useEffect` hook of `App.js`. Then I pass the filtered data to their respective component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('alldata').then((res) => {
        let allData = res.data;
         
        let compAData = allData.filter((data) => data.category === 'compA')
        setStateCompAData(compAData);
        let compBData = allData.filter((data) => data.category === 'compB')
        setStateCompBData(compBData);
        let compCData = allData.filter((data) => data.category === 'compC')
        setStateCompCData(compCData);
    })
},[])

return (<div>
    <CompA data={stateCompAData}/>
    <CompB data={stateCompBData}/>
    <CompC data={stateCompCData}/>
</div>)
```

**Scenario 3**

I don't call the API in `App.js` - I call the API every time in the components `useEffect and filter` in their respective component.

So what is the correct use case scenario?

Comment: There's no correct answer for this, all 3 are valid but the optimal way may be different depending on how the application scales

Answer (score 0):

All 3 will achieve the same results, but scenario 2 is likely best practice. However, I would not recommend maintaining 3 different state values, but instead having a single object state containing the different data structured as such

```
{
   dataA: ...,
   dataB: ...,
   dataC: ...
}
```